# C# LINQ Query How to Select between Start and END index

Tags: c#, linq

I have more than 100 K rows in in SQL Server. I want to select in blocks of 1000 rows, like 1-1000, then 1001-2000, then 2001-3000... until finish.

I use this code

```
var ff = ((from a in db.Customers select).Skip(i).Take(i+1000));
```

But it does not work. If you have other solution please advice me.

Comment: `var ff = (from a in db.Customers select a).Skip(i).Take(i+1000);` have you tried this?

Comment: @downvoters, this question is clear, concise and includes a minimum verifiable example.  If you have an issue with this question, please leave a polite comment stating why, so the OP (who is new to the site) has a chance to address your feedback, and learn from it.

Comment: I agree with @DoctorJones, can't fathom the down voting at drop of a pin, my +1 only to counter the down-votes

Comment: `Take` is the block size, so it should be `Take(1000)` and not `i+1000`.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't **select** anything, it should be something like

```
var ff = ((from a in db.Customers select a).Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000));
```

or fluently:

```
var ff = db.Customers.Skip(i * 1000).Take(1000);
```

Comment: You're right, I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggest to query all items to your local process and to divide the result into pages using Skip / Take.

This has the disadvantage that it would be quite a waste of processing power, if after the third pages you find that you don't need the other pages anymore: you've just fetched 1000 pages for nothing. The grand idea of LINQ is to delay the enumeration as much as possible: only fetch the items (maybe a few more) that you actually need.

Apart from that, your Skip would start at the first element every time you would ask for the next page, So if you ask for page 1000 of size 100, it will start at the first element, then skip 1000*100 elements before taking the next: what a waste of processing power!

Another suggestion involved sorting your complete collection, every time you ask for a page. Why sort the elements in your 1000th page, if you are fetching page 3?

Apparently you are not interested in the order of the Customers, so let's order them by primary key: Bingo: your Customers are already ordered by primary key!

When a page is requested we remember the primary key of the last returned element and when the next page is requested we start with the first Customer with a primary key larger than this last one.

I'll write it as an extension function of `IQueryable<Customer>`, where I exactly fetch one page only if you ask for the next page while enumerating. So if you stop enumerating after fetching page 3, page 4 and higher are not fetched.

```
private static IEnumerable<ICollection<Customer>> ToPages(
    this IQueryable<Customer> customers, int pageSize)
{
    int lastFetchedCustomerId = 0; // no primary key fetched yet

    // get the first page:
    var page = customers.Where(customer => customer.Id > lastFetchedCustomerId)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();

    // as long as there is a Customer in the page, return the page
    while (page.Count != 0)
    {   // there are customers
        yield return page;

        lastFetchedCustomerId = page[page.Count-1].Id;
        page = customers.Where(customer => customer.Id > lastFetchedCustomerId)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
     const int pageSize = 100
     IEnumerable<ICollection<Customer>> customerPages = dbContext.Customers.ToPages(pageSize);
     // note: nothing has been enumerated yet, no data has been fetched

     foreach (var customerPage in customerPages)
     {
         // one page has been fetched, we can do something with the Customers in the page
        foreach (Customer customer in customerPage)
        {
            ProcessCustomer(customer);
            bool continueProcessingCustomers = ...;

            if (!continueProcessingCustomers) return;
            // so if you break in page 3, the other pages are not fetched!
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you'll always fetch the Customers per page. So if you decide after processing the third customer that you don't need the rest of the customers of this page, they are fetched for nothing. But that is always better than having fetched all customers.

Finally, if you know that all your `DbSet` will have primary key in property Id, consider implementing interface IId, so ToCustomerPages can be used for all your tables:

```
interface IId
{
    public int Id {get;}
}
class Customer : IId
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    ...
}  

class Order : IId
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Generic version of ToCustomerPages:

```
private static IEnumerable<ICollection<TSource>> ToPages<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source, int pageSize)
    where TSource: IId
{
    ...
}
```

Now you will be able to get your orders in pages as well:

```
var orderPages = dbContext.Orders.ToPages(100);
```

Comment: Fetching all the data in the memory has an initial impact, but that's trade off to avoid a db round trip for every Next page call, also the mandatory primary key (clustered index) may not be always feasible. In fact for this solution we can even pass parameters to SP, instead of using IQueryable Linq. Generally when data is fetched in bulk, then it's cached for faster processing across user sessions. A Db round trip  would mostly not match the cached data performance. Generally it is use case dependent, but Cached data can accommodate many more query patterns

Answer (score 0):

In Linq to Entities you have to sort items in order to use `Skip`. Than you can use `Skip` to skip some records and `Take` to take other.

In example below inside `While` loop you have access to 1000 records each time (`part`). Records are sorted by `Id` use any other property if needed. `ToList()` is optional to materialize your result.

As suggested by Marnus you can skip getting count of all items.

```
 foreach (var page in db.Customers .OrderBy(x => x.Id).GetPages(1000))
 {
     // page is IEnumerable<Customer> with count 1000 or less
 }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPages<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageSize)
    {
        int i = 0;
        IEnumerable<T> page = null;
        while (page == null || page.Count() == pageSize)
        {
            page = source.Skip(i).Take(pageSize);
            i += pageSize;
            yield return page;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To detect the end you can just check if part is <1000. Than you dont need to query the total.